# My HTML Canvas went blank

Tags: javascript, html5, game-loop, html-canvas

I tried to draw Mario Sprites in my HTML Canvas, but it always went blank.
Anybody knows why?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mario;
var marioSprite;
var tiles;
var speedX = 1;

//marioSprite Specification
mario = {
    //target picture specification X & Y, Width & Height
    px:276,
    py: 44,
    pwidth: 16,
    pheight: 16,
    //drawing on Canvas specification X & Y, Width & Height
    cx: 16,
    cy: 116,
    cwidth:16,
    cheight:16,
}


//draw Mario in Canvas
function drawMarioSprite(){
    marioSprite = new Image();
    marioSprite.src = 'file:///C:/Users/MASTONO ALI/Desktop/img/characters.gif';
    marioSprite.addEventListener('load', e => {
    ctx.drawImage(marioSprite, 
        mario.px, mario.py, mario.pwidth, mario.pheight, 
        mario.cx, mario.cy, mario.cwidth, mario.cheight);
    });
    this.position = function() {
        this.mario.cx += speedX;       
    }
    position();
}//drawMarioSprite() end

//drawTiles and tilesLoop
function drawTiles() {
    tiles = new Image();
    tiles.src = 'file:///C:/Users/MASTONO ALI/Desktop/img/tiles.png';
    tiles.addEventListener('load', e => {
        tilesLoop();
    });
}
function tilesLoop(){
    for (let x = 0; x < 25; x++){
        for (let y = 11; y < 13; y++){
            ctx.drawImage(tiles, 
                0, 0, 26, 26, 
                x*12, y*12, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}//drawTiles() end


function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawMarioSprite();
    drawTiles();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to call the drawing code inside the `'load'` event handler, since for that to happen more than once, you would need to load the image multiple times which you also don't want to do. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)

You should load the images once at startup and then draw them from the pre-loaded data.

In this case, since you do the drawing code repeatedly with `requestAnimationFrame`, once the image actually loads it will be drawn correctly, if you just remove the `load` eventlisteners and just directly call the drawing code.

That is, change

```js
    marioSprite.addEventListener('load', e => {
    ctx.drawImage(marioSprite, 
        mario.px, mario.py, mario.pwidth, mario.pheight, 
        mario.cx, mario.cy, mario.cwidth, mario.cheight);
    });
```

to

```js
    ctx.drawImage(marioSprite, 
        mario.px, mario.py, mario.pwidth, mario.pheight, 
        mario.cx, mario.cy, mario.cwidth, mario.cheight);
```

and

```js
    tiles.addEventListener('load', e => {
        tilesLoop();
    });
```

to

```js
    tilesLoop();
```

Comment: One of the most annoying parts when doing game development in HTML+JavaScript is that you can never rely on any asset being actually loaded. Which is why I usually create a `Sprite` class which is both responsible for loading and drawing an image, and when the image didn't load yet, the `draw` function just does nothing. Another option is to use a preloader which loads all the assets and to not start rendering until the onload-callbacks of all assets were called.